# LibGDX Scene2d.ui shows only white screen with the following code

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

```
package com.Darth377Apps.DeepShadow;

import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.*;

public class MainMenu implements Screen
{

private Stage stage;
private Table table;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private TextButton buttonPlay, buttonExit;
private Label heading;
private BitmapFont white;
private Skin skin;
private TextButton TextButton;
@Override
public void create(){
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/button.pack");
    skin= new Skin(atlas);
    table=new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    white= new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Font/white.fnt"),false);
    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button.up.9");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button.down.9");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
    textButtonStyle.font = white;
    textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;

    buttonExit = new TextButton("EXIT",textButtonStyle);
    buttonExit.pad(20);

    table.add(buttonExit);
    stage.addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void render(float p1)
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    stage.act(p1);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int p1, int p2)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void show(){


}
@Override
public void hide()
{

}

@Override
public void pause()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void resume()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

}
```

When I run the app, only a white screen appears. The app definitely runs this code, as I ha e tested through logcat.

I am extremely confused as to why the text button does not appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to not set the bounds of the `Table`, but to use `table.setFillParent(true)` instead. Furthermore you need to implement `resize(...)` in the following way:

```
public void resize(int p1, int p2)
{
    stage.getViewport().update(p1, p2, true);
}
```